# Import Excel Spreadsheet into Existing MS Access Tables

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, ms-office

I have an Access database.  Here is the setup for a few tables.

id - companyID (autonumber) PK, company (text), firstName (text), lastName (text)

category - companyID (number) combined PK with category, category (text)

salesmen - companyID (number) combined PK with code, code (text)

There is a 1-many relationship between id and category and between id and salesmen.

If I have a spreadsheet with columns of company, firstName, lastName, category1, category2, category3, salesman1, salesman2, how could I import the columns into the appropriate tables?

My first idea was to import the spreadsheet and then append company, firstName and lastName to the id table.  Then I would join the imported spreadsheet with the id table to create a new table with all of the spreadsheet columns plus the auto generated companyID.  Then I could append companyID and category1 to the category table.  Then do the same for category2 and 3 and so on.

This seems really complicated if I have a lot of spreadsheets to import.  Also, the person who will be importing the spreadsheets isn't a programmer, so she wants it to be as user-friendly as possible.

Is there a better way to import these spreadsheets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create another table to import the raw data into, then `INSERT` the data from there into the relevant tables.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM ImportDataTable;")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "ImportDataTable", "C:\exceldata.xls"
```

The second line in Access VBA will import the data into the table called ImportDataTable (the ImportDataTable column names should be F1, F2, F3, etc.
Then use an append query (`INSERT INTO`) for each table that some of the ImportDataTable data needs to go in to. All this code can be put behind a button on a form so that the user(s) only need to press a button when new data is available.

Comment: How would I make sure that the companyID autonumber I get when I add a row to the id table matches the companyID that I insert into the category table?  I'm still not sure how to get the companyID added into the category and salesmen tables.  Is there a way I could prompt to allow the user to select an Excel file to import?